# How to prevent Navigation bar dim when Dialog is showing

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I set alertdialog's backgroundDimEnabled true, to add fullscreen mask

Here is the code
[image: Here is the code]

but I don't know how to prevent navigation bar dim

[image: Here is the screen]

Comment: <style name="MyDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom</item>
        <item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/CoolDialogXml</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CoolDialogXml</item>
    </style>

Comment: You can [edit] your question instead of adding code in comments